# Model binding not working in Springboot using Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-binding, lombok

Binding of property not happening for one of attribute in springboot rest controller where I'mn using Lombok @Data

Tried with own getter, setters instead of Lombok working fine.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/v1/getList")
    public List<String> getDetails(@RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, SQLException {}
```

RequestDTO model:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class RequestDTO {
    String type;
    String param;
    String requestId;
    String screenName;
}
```

Request Payload:

```
{"param":"a","type":"b","requestId":"c","screenName":"S - Name for ref"}
```

while sysout, I'm getting:
requestDTO.getScreenName(): null

Remaining properties are binding properly.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an error in method naming if others are working fine. usually getters and setters for this sName field should looks like this.

```
public string getsName() {
    return sName;
}

public void setsName(string sName) {
    this.sName = sName;
}
```

try using requestDTO.get**s**Name(); note that in here s is simple.

Comment: Thankyou Vimukthi_R. I am not specifying any custom getter setters. I am directly using Lombok generated getters setters with IDE. I am sure naming convention is fine. Can you please suggest further.

Comment: I have updated code snippet in question. I am using Lombok generated getter which is auto populating by eclipse IDE. No custom I am generating. Now with requestDTO.getScreenName() still its null.